# Linq - Select distinct objects

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to extract distinct objects by their values to have the unique `CurrencyISO` I have in the `.csv`.

```
public List<CurrencyDetail> InitGSCheckComboCurrency()
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Data/AccountsGSCheck.csv");
    var data = (from l in lines.Skip(1)
                let split = l.Split(',')
                select new CurrencyDetail
                {
                    ISOName = split[3],
                    ISOCode = split[3]
                }).Distinct();

    List<CurrencyDetail> lstSrv = new List<CurrencyDetail>();
    lstSrv = data.ToList();

    return lstSrv;
}
```

However, the distinct function does not work for this and I end up with duplications.

Comment: Typo? Both `ISOName` and `ISOCode` are *third* - `split[3]` - items?

Comment: Important distinction, do you want the distinct values or the unique ones?  For instance if you have 1,2,2,3 the distinct values are 1,2,3 but the unique ones are 1,3.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of `CurrencyDetail` to do what you want. Quick and dirty solution:

```
var data = (from l in lines.Skip(1)
           let split = l.Split(',')
           select new
           {
               ISOName = split[3],
               ISOCode = split[3]
           }).Distinct()
           .Select(x => new CurrencyDetail
           {
               ISOName = x.ISOName,
               ISOCode = x.ISOCode
           };
```

Anonymous types (the first `new { ... }`) automatically define sensible `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`. Normally I wouldn't do this, because you are creating objects to then discard them. For this reason it is a quick and dirty solution.

Note that you are using twice `split[3]`... an error?

Now, a fully equatable version of `CurrencyDetail` could be:

```
public class CurrencyDetail : IEquatable<CurrencyDetail>
{
    public string ISOName { get; set; }
    public string ISOCode { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // obj is object, so we can use its == operator
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        CurrencyDetail other = obj as CurrencyDetail;

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.InnerEquals(other);
    }

    public bool Equals(CurrencyDetail other)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.InnerEquals(other);
    }

    private bool InnerEquals(CurrencyDetail other)
    {
        // Here we know that other != null;

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return this.ISOName == other.ISOName && this.ISOCode == other.ISOCode;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            // From http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/613130
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + (this.ISOName != null ? this.ISOName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hash = hash * 23 + (this.ISOCode != null ? this.ISOCode.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can use the `Distinct()` as used by your code.